# How can I join across a has_many, a has_many :through and a HABTM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'd like to be able to write a single query to find all Messages a user has created, viewed or received.

This is a simplified version of my User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # user_id
  has_many :messages

  # message_viewer_id
  has_many :message_views, foreign_key: 'message_viewer_id'
  has_many :viewed_messages, through: :message_views

  # user_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :received_messages,
                          join_table: 'messages_recipients',
                          class_name: 'Message'
end
```

I've tried many variations of the following using `.where` and `.conditions` , but keep getting errors like `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "received_messages"`

```
User.
  joins(:messages,
        :message_views,
        :received_messages).
  where({messages: {user_id: id},
         message_views: {message_viewer_id: id},
         received_messages: {user_id: id}})
```

(I can join `:messages` and `:message_views` without issue, but the query breaks when I introduce `:received_messages`. (Yes, I know I shouldn't have used HABTM.))

What it the simplest and/or most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Switching from `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many ..., :through` isn't that hard. Since you're already using a custom table, so long as it has a primary key `id` column you could re-define it in terms of that pretty easily. If it's missing that column, that's easy to add with an `ALTER TABLE`. The `has_and_belongs_to_many` implementation in Rails 4.1 and earlier leaves a *lot* to be desired.

Comment: Thanks, @tadman, but I'd like to avoid changing the DB structure if possible. I may consider this if I can't figure out a viable alternative.

Comment: I think ActiveRecord 4.2 replaced the `has_and_belongs_to_many` implementation as part of the [AdequateRecord](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2014/02/19/adequaterecord-pro-like-activerecord.html) update, but you'd have to test to confirm. It's worth testing if the schema change and conversion to a first-class model solves any problems, short-term pain, as work-arounds are always messy to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
    def all_messages
      Message.where("user_id = ? OR id IN (SELECT message_id FROM message_views WHERE message_viewer_id = ?) OR id IN (SELECT message_id FROM messages_recipients WHERE user_id = ?)", self.id, self.id, self.id)
    end
    ...
end
```

I would recommend putting indexes on `user_id` on messages, `message_viewer_id` on message_views, and `user_id` on messages_recipients, if you haven't already.

Comment: I'll give this a try shortly. Thanks!

Comment: I had to tweak one of the foreign key column names, but this does work. Thank you!